# Fast way to execute MySQL stored procedures in Java within multiple threads?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

What is the fastest option to issue stored procedures in a threaded environment in Java? According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html#connector-j-examples-preparecall Connection.prepareCall() is an expensive method. So what's the alternative to calling it in every thread, when synchronized access to a single CallableStatement is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

The most JDBC drivers use only a single socket per connection. I think MySQL also use also a single socket. That it is a bad performance idea to share one connection between multiple threads.

If you use multiple connection between different threads then you need a CallableStatment for every connection. You need a CallabaleStatement pool for every connection. The simplest to pool it in this case is to wrap the connection class and delegate all calls to the original class. This can be create very fast with Eclipse. In the wrapped method prepareCall() you can add a simple pool. You need also a wrapped class of the CallableStatement. The close method return the CallableStatement to the pool.

But first you should check if the call is real expensive because many driver has already such poll inside. Create a loop of prepareCall() and close() and count the time.

Answer (score 0):

Connection is not thread safe, so you can't share it across threads.

When you prepareCall, the JDBC driver (may) be telling the RDBMS system to do a lot of work that is stored on the server side.  You may be guilty of premature optimization here.

Answer (score 0):

After giving this a little thought it seems that if you are having issues with this infrastructure code then your problems are elsewhere. Most applications do not take an inordinate amount of time doing this stuff.
Make sure you are using a DataSource, most do connection caching and some even do caching of statements.
Also for this to be a performance bottle neck it would imply that you are doing many queries one after the other, or that your pool of connections is too small. Maybe you should do some benchmarking on your code to see how much time the stored proc is taking vs how much time the JDBC code is taking.
Of course I would follow the MySQL recommendation of using CallableStatement, I am sure they have benchmarked this. Most apps do not share anything between Threads and it is rarely an issue.